# How the Haproxy roundrobin weighted algorithm works?

Tags: haproxy, round-robin

I would like to understand the load split in haproxy weighted method. For example

```
server serverA site1.example.com weight 45 check 
server serverB site2.example.com weight 45 check 
server serverc site3.example.com weight 10 check
```

I understand that the above example splits 45-45-10 out of 100 requests. 
My question is, the split will work only if the traffic has 100 or above concurrent requests, or if the server get 10 requests, the first 4 requests to serverA and next 4 requests to serverB and finally the 2 requests to serverC.

I have searched google for this question, still finding nothing.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algo will split or calculate based on every new connection, however serverA will always get the first connection...
It also depends on one of the following two options:
balance leastconn
balance roundrobin
And it also assumes you are not using any persistence/sticky methods.
Best way to understand it is to test it yourself (although it can be hard to test with short lived connections like HTTP.)